# Upgrading from lubuntu 18.04 to 18.10 on a encrypted LUKS partition

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, luks

So i've heard theres some problems with upgrading from bionic to cosmic. One of them was that luks and grub was changed a bit so that some systems wouldn't boot. If it helps, i installed lubuntu using the option to use the entire disk and encrypt it so it automatically partitioned the disk. I don't want to upgrade unless i know its good to do so.

Comment: Rumors don't mean much. Read the release notes to be sure. If your data is valuable enough to encrypt, then it seems valuable enough to backup before a release-upgrade. My release-upgrades to 18.10 were smooth and flawless and boring on my systems...but perhaps my systems are different from yours.

Comment: I'll have a go on upgrading on a vm first. Otherwise i'll wait for 19.04 to be released. You type 'sudo do-release-upgrade' to upgrade right?

Comment: You type `do-release-upgrade` without the `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** For me, apparently `cryptsetup` went missing during the upgrade. So make sure it's installed, then, do `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` to ensure that you don't end up with a system you cannot boot.

---

I had this kind of problem the rumors are about ;) Rebooting an old kernel worked first, but after the next `update-initramfs`, booting any kernel would fail:

`WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
Volume group "xubuntu-vg" not found.
Dave up waiting for suspend/resume device`

I fixed this by `chroot`ing into the broken system, installing `cryptsetup`, which apparently went missing during the upgrade (!!), and then properly doing `update-initramfs` from `chroot`. This is described [here](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/initramfs-dazubewegen-luks-lvm-zu-oeffen/#post-8828341) (unfortunately german, and when you follow it, make sure `boot` is mounted), but hopefully, it's not necessary when you fix the system before rebooting.